# .NET provides 8+ ways to encode data to prevent XSS attacks. Which one should I use when?

Tags: xss, csrf, .net, asp.net, encoding

I'm looking at ways to use .NET to prevent XSS attacks and have come across the following methods to encode data:

```
        string asdf = WebUtility.UrlEncode(code);
        string asdf1 = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);
        string asdf1a = HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(code); // OBSOLETE
        string asdf1b = HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(code);
        string asdf1c = Uri.EscapeDataString(code);
        string asdf1d = Uri.EscapeUriString(code);
        string asdf1e = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(code);
        string asdf1f = HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(code);
```

(I omitted the byte[] methods... but there are more)

Given that each one of these methods work in a completely different way, and are located in completely different classes I would assume it's easy to cause an XSS issue given the wrong mix of choices.

For a given situation, when is it appropriate to use a given encoding method?  Why?

Comment: It's worth looking at the [OWASP ESAPI](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI) project, which contains a whole bunch of filtering utilities designed to help prevent XSS in output destined for HTML (inside tags, attributes, etc.), JavaScript, and CSS. Sadly the .NET version isn't quite up-to-speed yet, but it's still usable.

Answer (score 5):

This is sort of **the** source for preventing XSS in ASP.NET (at least from Microsoft):

## [How To: Prevent Cross-Site Scripting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx)

Some important things to glean from the article specific to your question:

- Use the `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` method to encode output if **it contains input from the user or from other sources such as databases**.
- use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` to encode **output URLs if they are constructed from input**.

Regarding [`HTMLAttributeEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdek0zbf(v=vs.110).aspx):

- The HtmlAttributeEncode method converts only quotation marks ("), ampersands (&), and left angle brackets (<) to equivalent character entities. It is **considerably faster** than the `HtmlEncode` method.
- The string result from the `HtmlAttributeEncode` method **should be used only for double-quoted attributes**. Security issues might arise when using the `HtmlAttributeEncode` method with single-quoted attributes.

And finally, with [`UriEscapeString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring(v=vs.110).aspx), use that if what you are escaping is a [URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx). [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396598/whats-the-difference-between-escapeuristring-and-escapedatastring) discusses the difference between `UriEscapeString` and `UriEscapeDataString`.